# Update a map based on some condition

Tags: scala

I am trying to do an "update if present, put if not" like operation on a mutable `ParMap` in Scala. The best thing I could come up with was:

```
val update = if (myMap isDefinedAt aKey) {
    createValueForUpdate(...) 
} else {
    createValueForEmpty(...)
}

myMap updated(aKey, update)
```

Well, this works, but I am pretty sure there's a more functional way to solve this. Could you please provide some refactoring ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val update = myMap.get(aKey) match {
  case None => createValueForEmpty(...)
  case Some(value) => createValueForUpdate(...) 
}
```

or the equivalent `myMap.get(aKey).fold(createValueForEmpty(...))(value => createValueForUpdate(...))` (which may or may not be more readable depending on what `createValue...`s actually look like).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
val update = myMap.get(aKey).map(
    _ => createValueForUpdate(...)
    ).getOrElse(createValueForEmpty(...))
```